# Why I can't type in any Chinese punctuation characters in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, localization, cjk

For Emacs 23.2(9.0) on Mac OS X.

In the start-up screen, it has the following text

```
GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.29) of 2010-05-08 on black.local
```

I found i can't type in Chinese punctuation characters. For example, I can type in `,` but not `，`, and `"` but not `“` or `”`, etc. Typing in the former will result in the later.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the input method to `chinese-punct':

<kbd>C-1 C-\</kbd>`chinese-punct`

Afterwards, striking any punctuation key should produce in the minibuffer a list of related Chinese punctuation symbols, of which one may be selected using its corresponding number.